# How to solve number keyboard errors in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, keyboard, numbers

Applying the numeric keyboard format in the Flutter causes errors.
This error causes the keyboard to appear slowly when it first runs. What is the way to solve the error?

###### TextField Code Example

```
TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  inputFormatters: [
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
  ],
  ...,
),
```

###### Terminal Error Message

*Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitChoco-NumberPad; using 25889_PortraitChoco_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default*

[image]

Comment: OS Simulator -> I/O -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard try with this

Comment: I've already tried it. This error occurs on iPhones, not simulators.

Comment: How did you handle with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known issue with keyboard handling on iOS in Flutter 2.5:

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/89378
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/90068

Probably, your problem will be fixed as soon as the above issues are resolved.